# Apply prometheus metric relabelling "after" rules

Tags: prometheus

Is it possible to have a metric relabel config apply "after" rules have been run? I.e., I want to change the labels for things upstream that consume the rule-defined metrics, but don't want people writing rules with the "raw" metrics to worry about the additional labels when joining/aggregating/etc.

Doing the relabelling only for rule-defined metrics would be fine too; I don't need the labels on the raw metrics we're scraping from targets.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No it is currenly (Prometheus 2.25) not possible.

If you need it, you can open a feature request on Github: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues